# How to multiply numbers with each other in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a number for example 123, this is stored in an element let's say
`<Number>123</Number>`. I am looking for a solution written in XSLT 1.0 which can do something like: 1*2*3 and provide me the result as 6. The value in `Number` element can be in any length. I know i can do this through substring function and by storing the values one by one in variables but the problem is, i dont know the length of this field.

I could not write any xslt for this.

Can anyone help or suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling a recursive named template:

```
<xsl:template name="digit-product">
    <xsl:param name="digits"/>
    <xsl:param name="prev-product" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="product" select="$prev-product * substring($digits, 1, 1)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($digits) > 1">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="digit-product">
                <xsl:with-param name="digits" select="substring($digits, 2)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="prev-product" select="$product"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$product"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Working example: http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YJ

Note that this assumes the value of the passed *digits* parameter is an integer.